# CSS select last class of parent [without .last]

Tags: css, css-selectors

i tried to select the last class of an element with css but i could not find a way.

Example:

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li class="activ">Lorem</li>
   <li class="activ">Ipsum</li>
   <li class="activ">el</li>
   <li class="activ">delor</li>
   <li class="passiv">mia</li>
   <li class="passiv">patre</li>
   <li class="passiv">alpha</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: List is dynamically changing so it is **not** always the 4th element

CSS (not working)

```
ul li.activ:last-child {
     background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without adding a .last class or javascript?

Comment: `last:child` is typically on elements and not on specific classes. So you can select the last `li` under the `ul` but not the last `li` which has `activ` class.

Comment: I think it's not possible in pure css. Are you allergic to Javascript ? ^^  It's really easy to achieve this behavior using it.

Comment: this [class^="activ"]:last-child {background:red} would have been a solution but it's not working, im guessing you can't with pure css

Comment: i was just wondering if this is possible. I use Javascript only for things that CSS can't do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. You will need to use either one of those workarounds.